# How to use Simple Injector to inject a class into my custom model binder provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

I'm trying to build a simple blog website in MVC Core.

Currently, I have a a custom model binder provider which looks something like this (where IBlogRepository is my database repository using nHibernate):

```
public class PostModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    IBlogRepository _blogRepository;
    public PostModelBinderProvider(IBlogRepository blogRepository)
    {
        _blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }


    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

And it is registered like this:

```
services.AddMvc(config => config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new PostModelBinderProvider(container.GetInstance<IBlogRepository>())));
```

But then I get this exception when attempting to run the application:
`SimpleInjector.ActivationException: 'The ISession is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.'`

Currently, my front end makes an ajax call which sends the blog-post data (title, content and tags) to the server. The tags are represented by an integer which corresponds to their unique IDs in the database. The Model binder is doing a lookup on the database of the tag, and then saving the post.

So I have a look online, and there seems to be a divided opinion about whether I should be touching the database at all in the model binder.

Question:

- So, assuming that it's okay to get data from the database in the model binder, how do I make Simple Injector work with it?
- Alternatively, if it's not okay to get data from the database in the model binder, where would I put the logic for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PostModelBinderProvider is effectively a singleton, while the IBlogRepository is transient or scoped. Easiest solution is to change the IBlogRepository dependency to `Func <IBlogRepository>` instead and change the configuration to the following:

```
services.AddMvc(config => config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, 
    new PostModelBinderProvider(
          container.GetInstance<IBlogRepository>)));
```

Inside the PostModelBinderProvider you can now invoke the delegate to get the repository.